# Add shortcut to open specific url in browser - Intellij Shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to add Shortcut to open specific URL (let say localhost:3000) in IntelliJ. I read the documentation and try to figure it out on my own by messing around the Keymap, but No luck. Is this possible? What I want is to create a shortcut to open specific URL. If my custom shortcut is `Alt +;` then it should open http://localhost:3000. Is this feasible in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this with the following steps...

**1. Define an external Tool for Localhost**

- File > Settings...
- Tools > External Tools
- Define your Tool with

  - Program: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  (in Windows 10)
  - Arguments: http://localhost:3000

[image]

**2. Define your shortcut**

- File > Settings...
- Keymap
- Choose External Tools > Localhost on the right side
- Right click and choose 'Add Keyboard Shortcut'

[image]

- Type your Shortcut
- You should see it in the dialog

[image]

**3. Use the Shortcut**

Hope it helps.

Comment: absolutely a breeze... thanks a lot. Now I can open Jacoco test report in a keystroke.